# BarChart include multiple fields on x-axis

Tags: plotting

I want to chart data using a BarChart, the labels on the x-axis should consist of three values, however I can only use one of the values (the street name), where I would like to include the city and country name.

The relevant piece of code:

```
rEntities = {{1261, "C/O C T Corporation System", "Boston", 
"UNITED STATES"}, {1017, "C/O National Registered Agents, Inc.", 
"New York", "UNITED STATES"}, {1004, "49, Avenue J.F. Kennedy", 
"Luxembourg", "LUXEMBOURG"}, {799, 
"C/O National Corporate Research, Ltd.", "Dover", 
"UNITED STATES"}, {793, "C/O CT Corporation System", "Boston", 
"UNITED STATES"}}

BarChart[#, ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow", 
PlotLabel -> Framed[Text[Grid[{
    {Style["Entities with same address", Blue, FontSize -> 18]},
    {Style["Address's with 200 to 6999 entities", Red, 
      FontSize -> 12]}}]]], 
ChartLabels -> (Placed[
  Rotate[Style[#, Black], Pi/3] & /@ #2, {{.7, 0}, {1, 1}}])] & @@
Transpose[rEntities]
```

[image: only 1 field on x-axis]

What I would like to see would be the city and country as well. 
For example:
"C/O C T Corporation System, Boston, UNITED STATES" under the blue bar.
"49, Avenue J.F. Kennedy, Luxembourg, LUXEMBOURG" under the olive bar, etc.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Replace `#2` with an array containing the information you are interested in (e.g. `Transpose[{#2, #3}]` and then use `Column[#]` to format the label as desired.

```
rEntities = {{1261, "C/O C T Corporation System", "Boston", 
   "UNITED STATES"}, {1017, "C/O National Registered Agents, Inc.", 
   "New York", "UNITED STATES"}, {1004, "49, Avenue J.F. Kennedy", 
   "Luxembourg", "LUXEMBOURG"}, {799, 
   "C/O National Corporate Research, Ltd.", "Dover", 
   "UNITED STATES"}, {793, "C/O CT Corporation System", "Boston", 
   "UNITED STATES"}}

BarChart[#, ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow", 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Framed[Text[
      Grid[{{Style["Entities with same address", Blue, 
          FontSize -> 18]}, {Style[
          "Address's with 200 to 6999 entities", Red, 
          FontSize -> 12]}}]]], 
   ChartLabels -> (Placed[
      Rotate[Style[Column[#, Alignment -> Right], Black], Pi/3] & /@ 
       Transpose@{#2, #3}, {{.7, 0}, {1, 1}}])] & @@ 
 Transpose[rEntities]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
BarChart[#, ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow", 
 PlotLabel -> Framed[Text[Grid[{
    {Style["Entities with same address", Blue, FontSize -> 18]},
    {Style["Address's with 200 to 6999 entities", Red, 
      FontSize -> 12]}}]]], 
    ChartLabels -> (Placed[
       Rotate[Style[Row[Riffle[#, ", "]], Black, 8], Pi/5] & /@ Transpose[{#2, #3, #4}], {{.7, 0}, {1, 1}}])] & @@
 Transpose[rEntities]
```

Change value of Placed:

```
BarChart[#, ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow", 
 PlotLabel -> Framed[Text[Grid[{
    {Style["Entities with same address", Blue, FontSize -> 18]},
    {Style["Address's with 200 to 6999 entities", Red, 
      FontSize -> 12]}}]]], 
    ChartLabels -> (Placed[
       Rotate[Style[Row[Riffle[#, ", "]], Black, 8], Pi/2] & /@ Transpose[{#2, #3, #4}], Below])] & @@
 Transpose[rEntities]
```

or use ChartLegends:

```
BarChart[#, ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow", 
 PlotLabel -> Framed[Text[Grid[{
    {Style["Entities with same address", Blue, FontSize -> 18]},
    {Style["Address's with 200 to 6999 entities", Red, 
      FontSize -> 12]}}]]], 
    ChartLegends -> (Placed[
       Style[Row[Riffle[#, ", "]], Black, 8] & /@ Transpose[{#2, #3, #4}], Below])] & @@
 Transpose[rEntities]
```

Comment: I like your solution the best, however when using it where there are 50 columns I need to rotate the label's so they are vertical and under their respective bar.

Comment: I tried `code` BarChart[#, ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow", AspectRatio -> .3, 
   ImageSize -> 600, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Framed[Text[
      Grid[{{Style["Entities with same address", Blue, 
          FontSize -> 18]}, {Style[
          "Address's with 200 to 6999 entities", Red, 
          FontSize -> 12]}}]]], 
   ChartLabels -> (Placed[
      Rotate[Style[Row[Riffle[#, ", "]], Black, 10], Pi/2] & /@ 
       Transpose[{#2, #3, #4}], {{4, 0}, {3, 1}}])] & @@ 
 Transpose[rEntities]

Comment: @sente I added that option